# Как проверить заголовок origin в использовании websocket на основе socket.io?

Tags: node.js, websocket

Как проверить заголовок origin в использовании websocket на основе socket.io?

В library - 'ws' это делается так:

```
  var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({
    port: 8081, verifyClient: function(info, callback) {
                                if(info.origin != null){
                                  if(info.origin == 'http://ws-nodejs') {
                                      callback(true);
                                  }else{
                                     callback(false);
                                  }
                              }
  });
```

А как проверить этот заголовок в библиотеке socket.io?

Answer (score 1):

```
var io=require('socket.io');
server = io(server,{
    //бла бла
});
server.on('connection', function (connection) {
    console.log(connection.handshake.headers.origin);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но я прошу пр за размытость своего вопроса. Необходимо  узнать headers.origin `до` события `connection`. Собственно это как раз и показано в том коде который я приложил к вопросу но только это отражено в библиотеки `ws`

Comment: Т.е. вы телепатически хотите узнать кто к вам сейчас подключится, до того как он подключится?

Comment: Нет, не телепатически. Причем тут телепатия? В `ws` это же возможно. До события коннекшен можно узнать всю инфу.

Comment: Проверить инфу первого пакета входа на вебсервер

Comment: @Darth Хо-хо-хо, умник опАзорился )

Comment: @Юрий Светлов При помощи доп.либы внимательнее читайте офф доки!

Comment: А конкретнее указать не могли бы?